# How are Firebase Reads charged on snapshot whereField?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In this example from the firebase documentation:

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection

let citiesRef = db.collection("cities")

// Create a query against the collection.

let query = citiesRef.whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
```

Suppose I were to add a snapshot listener to the query and use it when a page appears. Would I be charged a read for every city in the collection of "cities" or just the cities where the state is equal to CA? For the query to work, it seems like it would have to search through every city, and I'm wondering if those would count as reads.

Comment: SwiftUI is a framework for displaying UI components on the screen -- this question doesn't seem to relate to it at all.

Comment: "it seems like it would have to search through every city" -- no, that's why databases have indexes, which help prevent that. You would not be charged for a read on every city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only charged for documents that need to be read on the server for API calls. Queries are actually handled by accessing one or more indexes, so there is no charge for the query itself (*) only for the documents that are actually returned to the client.

(*) the only exception to this is when there are no results for a query, in which case you'll be charged 1 document read.

Comment: Is there any easiest document about firebase charges on per read/write/edit/delete ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/pricing